# Are the sites automatically tested using Selenium?

Tags: discussion, browser-support

Are automated tests, using a tool like [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29), run over the sites as part of the normal build pipeline?

Given there have been several layout bugs with the new CSS/design, when detected/reported, are (failing) automated tests written to capture the regression?

Does the Stack Exchange development team use [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development)?

<sub>(It seems not, or not enough.)</sub>

Comment: The worst design bugs are things not capturable by Selenium, e.g. the way too low contrast of highlighted questions. As the Joel Test score of SE indicates, they do not have any testers - maybe they should use some of the $40m they just scored to hire one or two.

Comment: @l4mpi even contrast problems can be captured: given background and text r, g and b: `assert abs(bgr - tr) + abs(bgg - tg) + abs(bgb - tb) < VISIBLE_THRESHOLD;` or some formula that someone somewhere must surely have figured out and published. It can't be that hard. I thought the days of "release it and wait for the phone to ring to find where the bugs are" were over.

Comment: They have 3.3 million testers that all know how to write a bug report and know where to file it.  The few times that a bug actually interfered with the proper operation of the site, that bug got fixed in a few minutes.

Comment: A comprehensive Selenium-based suite would easily catch problems [like this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284170/why-should-this-question-be-closed-overlay-doesnt-close-upon-voting).

Comment: @Bohemian Indeed someone has come up with a formula - [W3 themselves](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G17.html).

Comment: @JamesThorpe. Huh. I guess math is useful for computer science. :V

Comment: @Compass well, yeah...

Comment: @HansPassant: Absolutely. Stack Exchange has a more involved and technically knowledgeable than almost any site on the Internet, who even have a special place file reports. I haven't seen a single bug report here on meta that doesn't at the very least contain steps to reproduce. And most of them also include most of the debugging work, already done. Some even include the solution.