# "Why should this question be closed" overlay doesn't close upon voting

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Starting some time this morning, when I vote to close a question, the vote is successful, but the "Why should this question be closed?" pane doesn't go away.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the "You've voted to close this question" appears underneath the overlay, next to the "Too broad" choice, and the "Votes remaining ..." progress bar just keeps spinning happily along, but the window never closed.

Not really a deal-breaker, I just click the [X] and move on, but I don't remember it doing this before.

[image]

I'm using Chrome, Version 39.0.2171.99 m, and have tried closing the browser and re-opening it, just to make sure it wasn't a temporary browser issue.

I also don't know if this applies to the greater Stack Exchange network or not; I haven't tried closing anything on the Stack Exchange Meta yet today.

Comment: Was about to report the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed with build rev `2015.1.21.2980` on meta and `2015.1.21.2207` on sites. The bug was introduced while fixing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284162/155005).

Comment: I see someone else subscribes to my Fix A Bug, Add A Bug philosophy ;)

Comment: Out of curiosity, when does the next build roll out?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables your philosophy's pluralization is wrong though. The 2nd Bug is > 1 most of the time.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284172/i-cant-add-a-stack-snippet-to-a-post see?

Comment: This was certainly annoying this morning.

Comment: It seems I still had the same (or a similar) issue when retracting an earlier close vote (on MSE to be precise). Could you have a look perhaps? Then I don't need to open a new report.

Comment: @Bart thanks, fixed in sites build rev `2015.1.30.2259`