# I can't add a Stack Snippet to a post

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I recently ran across [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/css-transition-height-0-to-height-auto) that, for all its votes and popularity, seemed pretty lacking (had a JSFiddle but only a few instances of a `ul` as far as code in the post goes, among other things), so I tried to add the JSFiddle code to a built-in Stack Snippet.

However, when I tried to click <kbd>Insert into post</kbd> on the Stack Snippet, nothing happened. I abandoned the Stack Snippet and tried again a couple times, but I was forced to abandon the Stack Snippet in order to submit my edit. Is this the case for all Protected Questions or is there something else at play here? I have successfully added Stack Snippets to posts before.

This is the first Stack Snippet I have attempted to add since the Stack Overflow site overhaul, so it could be affecting all questions; I am not sure.

I'm on Firefox v34.0

Comment: did you check console?

Comment: reproduced, on it

Comment: checked console, no errors.

Comment: Are you sure it's because it's a protected question? I can't seem to insert into any question or answer protected or not. Have to click directly on the black overlay

Comment: @Spokey I am not sure (I do offer that it might be another reason in my question), I haven't tried adding it to other questions *since the StackOverflow update*. It could be broken due to that.

Comment: @m0sa [looks like it isn't just that post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284175/insert-into-post-on-code-snippet-not-working)

Comment: This is effecting all questions for me.  Yay.

Comment: fix incoming.. you can click on the lightbox background in the meantime instead

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m for **all** questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with build rev `2015.1.21.2980` on meta and `2015.1.21.2207` on sites.