# "Insert Into Post" on Code Snippet not working

Tags: bug

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069965/select-div-with-specific-attr-and-not-specific-value/28070383#28070383) I am trying to insert a code snippet, but the "Insert Into Post" button does nothing.  The console doesn't show any errors.  See screenshots below:

[image]
[image]

My browser is Chrome 39.0.2171.99 m